# Function Prototype/Definition

Tags: c++, c

If we do not mention the function prototype,call the function from the main and write the definition after main it gives an error.If we write the function definition before main and do not write the prototype the program works fine. So my question is if we write the function definition before main(without writing the prototype) does it solve the problem of not declaring a function prototype(i.e, the compiler will start reading from top-down and will still be able to know about the function name,return type,parameters and etc)

Comment: A function definition includes the declaration of the function if it hasn't been declared before.

Comment: Also, what happens if you call a function when it hasn't been declared before differs between C and C++. C and C++ have some likeness, but they are indeed very different languages with very different semantic rules. So if you want a definitive answer in the future, please pick one language.

Comment: I think C and C++ are very different in this respect. You should specify which one you're using, or what kind of compatibility you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the function with no prior prototype is semantically equivalent to declaring the prototype immediately before defining the function. So yes, it's safe: defining a function without a prototype, before any uses of the function, will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler goes at function definition when you make a call to that function. While function prototype is consulted for arguments and return type checking. So, you can safely emit function prototype in your case...

Answer (score 0):

Yes (for C++), compiler will accept this. To call a function compiler must see its prototype or definition before. Also translation units (cpp) files are compiled from top to bottom, so:

```
void foo();
void foo2() {
}

int main() {
   foo();
   foo2();
}

void foo() {
}
```

are both correct. If you would provide `foo()` prototype without defining `foo` below main(), compiler will still accept your code, but linker would complain with error.

Comment: @ Marcin Jedrzejewski If we write void foo() as the prototype and call this function in the main and do not define the function below main as u have said,the compiler gives an error undefined reference to foo() ?

Comment: @Rooney10 yes, but thats actually linker that will issue error, compilation is in two phases first all the translation units are compiled, then all the resulting object files are linked. Compiler is not aware where you might have defined foo() it could be defined in some other translation unit (.cpp file).